# How accurate is Tezuka's manga Buddha?

Tags: buddha

Osama Tezuka's manga "Buddha" details the life of Buddha and consists of eight large volumes.

I have read a couple of  reviews that say the story is quite accurate, but some also declare the opposite - that Tezuka has taken too many liberties with the story.

How close do the volumes align with the Buddha's actual life?

[image]

Comment: considering that the birthplace of Buddha is debated till now, it cannot be said for sure what happened and didn't. but yeah its fairly accurate. Buddha's Wikipedia article is a good read.